# How to make jar app waiting "return" key before exit? (Clojure)

Tags: java, jar, clojure, leiningen

If I'll type 'let [exit (read)]' at the end, program will wait 'till I input something, but not for just enter key.
Is there a function which waiting user "return" key input?

Comment: you can add a while ( ) to check whether something was actually entered

Comment: @Stultuske read already waits until something gets entered before the user presses return. I understand the question that way, that LavX64 want to be able to end when the user is just pressing the return key.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can just replace the call to `read` with a call to `read-line`:

```
(let [exit (read-line)])
```

Comment: This works for me:
(defn -main                                                                      
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."                                              
  [& args]                                                                       
  (println "Hello, World!")                                                      
  (let [exit (read-line)]))

Comment: BTW: As you don't want to work with the data that has been read, it can be simplified to:
(defn -main                                                                      
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."                                              
  [& args]                                                                       
  (println "Hello, World!")                                                      
  (read-line))

Comment: It's working for me too, but only in "Hello, world!" program, can I send you my code so you can look where is the problem?